# Android: Detect Scroll Event for EditText

Tags: android, scroll, android-edittext

I am having problems with a seemingly very simple thing- I want to run code every time the user (or the program) scrolls the EditText up or down, in the same way a TextChanged listener allows you to run code every time the user or program changes the text. Is this possible? Thanks!

Comment: You mean if u have large number of data then ?? right ?

Comment: No- what I mean is: take as an example the TextChanged listener. When the text is changed it runs some code. I want the equivalent for Scrolling- how can I run code when the editText is scrolled (by the user and pogramatically)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try extending EditText and overriding:

onScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt)

which is inherited from TextView.